# Android sdk: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm getting this error when I try to debug the app on my device and trying to get rid of it in hours now...and cannot figure it out...Would be awesome if someone could find the solution since I want to release a new update for my app as soon as possible..

```
07-05 22:45:02.550    2821-2821/davvarn.csgo_maps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: davvarn.csgo_maps, PID: 2821
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{davvarn.csgo_maps/davvarn.csgo_maps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
            at davvarn.csgo_maps.MainActivity.changeContent(MainActivity.java:176)
            at davvarn.csgo_maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I do not really know how to paste the `MainActivity` file here, cause I'm new to Stackoverflow. Please let me know how and I will make a try.

Comment: You have calling setImageDrawable on null object (this is an imageview). It's difficult to say how to fix it because are you not pasted code.

Comment: The problem is in davvarn.csgo_maps.MainActivity class in changeContent method.

Comment: @krystian71115 so show your MainActivity class code, please

Comment: The problem is in this line: 176. I see it in your pasted logcat. Go to this line and detect why instance of imageview is null. You can click on edit (below your question) and add this line to question.

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to set this variable and it is null. Check answer of Zack Matthews.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! But where can I upload the code?

Comment: Click on edit below your question. And use copy and paste.

Comment: You can use https://pastebin.com and edit answer and paste the url.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about that site but couldnt remember the name of it. And also the explanation in the code is some part in English and other Swedish. (I hope it doesnt matter...) http://pastebin.com/GnL3yvZn

Comment: If you are want to reply for someone comment add this at top of comment : @username

Comment: @Davvarn It seems ok. Paste activity_main.xml maybe you have forgot something.

Comment: Its the whole MainActivity but i got a few more Java classes, i could upload  all of them... if thats nessessary.. I got the problem after i implemented Material Designed Tabhost

Comment: Inside directory Tabs: http://pastebin.com/FA0zuByS , http://pastebin.com/Qwms8pXX , http://pastebin.com/UziAtKuG

Comment: Inside view folder: http://pastebin.com/7ua5DTbk , http://pastebin.com/wxmTwc3c

Comment: I was using this for making material designed tabhost: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Comment: My activity_main.xml: http://pastebin.com/DQa7Tpre

Comment: And this the dependencies in build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/2W22bwRq

Comment: if anyone want, I could send the whole project (might be easier?)

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you've initialized your image view and are using the correct id defined in your XML. You can initialize your ImageView like this:

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewIDHere);`

Make you do this after your onCreate calls setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

Hoping this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.xml inside Imageview, instead of using **android:src** or **app:srcCompat** use property :

```
android:background="@drawable/yourfilename"
```

Hopefully this would help to someone whenever getting the exception either

1). while setting background resource to Imageview

2). or to update the imageview resource or to perform some action based on current resource by getting the current background resource from Imageview using

```
YourImageView.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YourImageView).getConstantState())
```